# Clone, replica, etc. - what are the differences?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Is clone and replica exactly the same?  Do they both convey an exact likeness in all properties?  Or is one or the other indicative of an exact likeness while the other indicative of a rough likeness.

I will be using the term in an IT context: is one of these terms better for two computers that share the exact same functionality (including operating system and installed and running applications) but may differ in terms of hardware?

Is there an alternate word anyone can think of (I obviously looked at a thesaurus but could not find anything that to me stood out as appropriate).
10x.

Comment: In IT jargon, _clone_ usually indicates that one computer (or at least the contents of its drives) is created from a binary image of another. If they differ in hardware but have the same functionality, I would use _equivalent_.

Comment: I'd specifically say *VHD or operating system is cloned (on another machine)*. It would be understood that hardware may or may not be the same.

Comment: I can't understand how in the word this question could be considered off -topic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an IT context:

A clone is functionally identical.  It may appear completely different.  See IBM PC clones such as a Mac Book.

A replica is superficially identical.  It may have hidden differences.  See [Raspberry PI gameboy replica](http://makezine.com/2014/07/11/make-your-own-raspberry-pi-gameboy-replica/)

A fake or counterfeit is a replica that is marketed while hiding the fact that it is a replica and not the real thing.  This is still true even if it is a perfect clone since the manufacturer is different.

Comment: +1 That's an interesting distinction. It certainly fits the way PC *clones* of the '80s were termed. Replicas can even be non-functional, e.g. a *wooden* replica of some famous machinery.